# How to know if a variable is true or false in one line

Tags: c

I have this piece of code:

```
NOTFREGbits.ro = ((NOTFREGbits.STS ? 3 : (1 + ((ZONEREG & 15) * 2))));
```

Where `NOTFREGbits.ro` is a 3 bit variable that stores the amount of times that an LED has to blink, depending on the state of `NOTFREGbits.STS`  and `ZONEREG` .

If `NOTFREGbits.STS` is true, the LED has to blink exactly three times (handled in another part of the code). Now, if `NOTFREGbits.STS` is false, depending on the state of the first four bits of `ZONEREG` (the first 4 bits are filtered by a mask of 15) if there are no 1's, the LED should blink only one time, but if there is at least one 1 or more, the LED should blink three times.

In the piece of code I've pasted, the behaviour expected when `NOTFREGbits.STS` is false, is followed only if the LSB of `ZONEREG` is the one changing states. If any other bit or any other combination of bits changes states, the amounts the LED blinks get out of what it should be.

One alternative that works would be this:

```
NOTFREGbits.ro = ((NOTFREGbits.STS ? 3 : (1 + (!!(ZONEREG & 15) * 2))));
```

I guess the `!` operand takes takes every bit after the mask and "does something" to know if its true or false, and then inverts the state. Thats why the second `!`  is there, to "anti-invert" the expression.

The question would be: Is there any other and cleaner way of doing so?

Comment: `!!` is used to ensure that all non-zero values yield 1 and zero value yields 0.

Comment: "...in one line"  ***WHY?!?!?!***

Comment: why not? I like to make code look very compact as long as the functionality isnt affected

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would honestly recommend:

```c
if (NOTFREGbits.STS) {
    NOTFREGbits.ro = 3;
} else if (ZONEREG & 15) {
    NOTFREGbits.ro = 3;
} else {
    NOTFREGbits.ro = 1;
}
```

Simple, clean, easy to understand, and *maintainable*. Don't try to get too clever - the saved cycles are very, very rarely worth it, and your compiler can often do a better job of optimizing the code when it's written simply.

Comment: This is also far less error-prone to modify. And to write in the first place - you can tell absolutely what it's doing and if it's right, with line noise code you can't. "There are two types of code, one obviously has no bugs, in the other no bugs are obvious" - quote from someone I don't remember.

Comment: @JohnBayko I believe it might have been Peter van der Linden who wrote "clever code is bad code", which is also apropos here.

Answer (score 2):

> The question would be: Is there any other and cleaner way of doing so?

As far as I got you problem, I suppose that

```
NOTFREGbits.ro = NOTFREGbits.STS || (ZONEREG & 15) ? 3 : 1;
```

…should do the trick. The `||` operator will automatically convert both its operands to boolean and also have an higher priority than ternary operator `? :`.

Note that bitwise `&` have an even higher priority, which would enable you to get rid of the last pair of parenthesis here, but this will make the code more confusing to the reader.

Comment: Although `||` does have (slightly) higher precedence than `?:`, as a matter of code style, I would have an easier time reading that if the `||` sub-expression were enclosed in parentheses.

Comment: Nobody prevents you to do so :-) But frankly, I tend to go back to expressions that are as light as possible. One should not be forced to know operator precedences by heart, but && over || and & over | should be as natural than × over +, and unnecessary parenthesis nesting should be left to LISP. Same for brackets { }. People used to write complicated expression two decades ago, then went too far from them. We should focus again on trusting programmers to write elegant stuff.

Comment: To each their own, I suppose, but I do not put `||` over `?:` in the same category as `&&` over `||` and `*` over `+`.  And if you only ever write code for yourself then that's one thing, but most people write code that other people, often less enlightened than you, will need to read from time to time.  Why make them work harder than necessary, or, worse, facilitate them making errors?  Source code should be written to be read.  Sometimes that means parentheses that are not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any other and cleaner way of doing so?

In real production coding, being able to trace code back to source requirements is *very* useful.

Consider the requirements of:

> If NOTFREGbits.STS is true, the LED has to blink exactly three times (handled in another part of the code). Now, if NOTFREGbits.STS is false, depending on the state of the first four bits of ZONEREG (the first 4 bits are filtered by a mask of 15) if there are no 1's, the LED should blink only one time, but if there is at least one 1 or more, the LED should blink three times.

And then code, much like [@nneonneo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76739586/2410359) with references to the requirements.

```
// If NOTFREGbits.STS is true, the LED has to blink exactly three times.
if (NOTFREGbits.STS) {
  NOTFREGbits.ro = 3;

// Now, if NOTFREGbits.STS is false, depending on the state of the 
// first four (least significant) bits of ZONEREG 
// if there are no 1's, the LED should blink only one time, 
// but if there is at least one 1 or more, the LED should blink three times.
} else {
  if ((ZONEREG & 15) == 0) {
    NOTFREGbits.ro = 1;
  } else {
    NOTFREGbits.ro = 3;
  }
}

Very clearly meets the requirements.
```

Answer (score 0):

> I guess the ! operand takes takes every bit after the mask and "does
> something" to know if its true or false, and then inverts the state.
> Thats why the second ! is there, to "anti-invert" the expression.

No. It is very simple.

- `!x` is `0` if `x` is not zero and is `1` if `x` is zero.
- `!!x` is `1` if `x` is not zero and is `0` if `x` is zero.

You can also:

```
NOTFREGbits.ro = NOTFREGbits.STS * 3 + !NOTFREGbits.STS * (1 + (!!(ZONEREG & 15) * 2))));
```

Comment: Frankly, this is unmaintainable junk.

Comment: @AndrewHenle as per OPs order

Comment: Yep. True dat...